# codesynthesis XSD generate C struct instead of C++ class

Tags: c, xsd, ada, codesynthesis

Is it possible to configure [Code Synthesis XSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/) to generate C-structs instead of C++ classes? The main issue is where multiple occurrences of an element is implemented as a std::list. The issue I've got is I need to interoperate with Ada and binding Ada to template classes in C++ is non-trivial. Therefore, if I can tune codesynthesis to generate structs then this simplifies the situation. Obviously, I could write (autogenerate) a C-layer which takes the C++ classes and turns them into structs but I'd rather not have to do this if possible! Any ideas?